# CDC not working for update data on SQL Server 2014 SP2

Tags: sql-server-2014

Please help me to fix this problem. I use SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 2. I have enabled the CDC on my database and table.

It worked when I did `INSERT` and `DELETE` operations (the tracking records were added to the CDC table) but the problem is: when I did `UPDATE` operation, there is nothing added to the CDC table.

So, what should I handle or fix with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the table has nothing?

1)
It depends. In certain implementations, when for example, you update the column used in clustered index when it is not primary key, the UPDATE statement is treated by system as combination of DELETE/INSERT operations, so you may see one DELETE and one INSERT operation in such cases.

Note that such INSERT/DELETE operations may be in incorrect order (this CDC bug is confirmed by MS, they're fixing it at the moment), so Get Net Changes function may return incorrect results (duplicate or missing rows).

2) What kind of updates did you perform? If you update the column to the same value, the change won't be there. Please post your scripts to better understand the problem.